# How train a CNN using stft matrix as inputs

Tags: python, audio, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, librosa

I try to train an autoencoder using stft as inputs (stft without passing by spectrogramms) and I'm new in audio processing and deep learning so I find some difficult in how I can preprocessing my inputs to be ready    for our model

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import IPython.display as ipd
import soundfile as sf
from scipy.io import wavfile
import os
import tensorflow as tf
# path
audio_dir='/content/drive/MyDrive/audio2/0'
output_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/audio2/output'

#convert wav to stft
audio_list=[]
stft=[]

for file_name in os.listdir(audio_dir):
  if file_name.endswith('.wav'):
    file_path = os.path.join(audio_dir, file_name)
    y,sr = librosa.load(file_path, sr=16000) # y -> array time series (my_audio as np.array)
    y = np.array(y)
    stft_lib = np.abs(librosa.stft(y, n_fft=1024, hop_length=512, window='hann'))
    audio_list.append(y)
    stft.append(stft_lib )

#resize the stft then convert it to np.array
resized_stft_list = []

# Define the target shape
target_shape = (512, 64, 2)

# Iterate over each STFT matrix in the list and resize it
for stft in stft_list:
    resized_stft = np.resize(stft, target_shape)
    resized_stft_list.append(resized_stft)

# Convert the resized STFT list to a NumPy array
resized_stft_array = np.array(resized_stft_list)
#split the data
train_ratio = 0.8
train_stft, val_stft = train_test_split(resized_stft_array, train_size=train_ratio, random_state=42)
```

this code gives me a (**ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()** ) when i try to fit a simple autoencoder with resized_stft_list as inputs how I can fix this